# How to apply a CSS stylesheet to a single page in userContent.css?

Tags: css, firefox, css-selectors, overlay

In Firefox, I am trying to apply CSS styles via a userContent.css overlay to a page with a URL format of (replace `xx` with `tt`):

> `hxxps://site.com/#s/`

I do not want the CSS to apply to:

> `hxxps://site.com/`

Thus, I encapsulate my rules in:

```css
@-moz-document url("hxxps://site.com/#s/") { ... }
```

But this does not work.

What code will allow this to work, if any?

Answer (score 0):

- Match an exact URL 'youtube.com' **ex:**

`@-moz-document domain(youtube.com) {...}`.

- Match if the document URL is on 'about:profiles' (or on a subdomain of it). **ex:**

`@-moz-document url(about:profiles) {...}`

- Match if the document URL starts with 'about:'. ex:

`@-moz-document url-prefix("about:") {...}`

Comment: Thank you for the attempt at helping, but unfortunately, none of these will result in the desired functionality.

Comment: if you want to match the exact url, you can use regex for that. ex: `@-moz-document regexp("^hxxps://site\.com/#s/$") {...}` but you have to reload twice to see if it really taking effect. 

you can use an [website](https://regex101.com/) to create regex. but i would not recomment using that as regex is said to be depricated, and doing it with userChrome.js will be overkill.